# Refreshing Android Views with Fragments is Problematic

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app, there are many views that contain a number of different fragments. For all the documentation about the vaunted lifecycle of Activities and how to hook into the various things that can happen to a view, I don't see any discussion in the documentation about views that can change based on events. So for instance, I have a view and at a certain time of day I want to hide one fragment and put another one in the view.

Getting this to work was pretty simple, however, now that I am trying to do tests of the activities, I keep getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1343)
```

For now, I am calling:

```
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

but there has to be a better way. I should be able to reconfigure the fragments in the view and then refresh, having Android resave the state and thus not complain about this.. ?

Comment: try transaction.commit();

Comment: I am doing transaction.commit and that's what makes the error come up about not calling it after onSaveInstance. By changing to commitAllowingStateLoss() it works, but it's not the right solution.